# raid not clean after shudown

Tags: shutdown, raid

I have a XUbuntu 22.04 LTS desktop system with RAID 1 (2 disks), and often after a normal desktop shutdown, when I boot up again I get the following message on `dmesg` and the kernel spends more than an hour recovering the array.

```
[    2.391724] md/raid1:md0: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
[    2.391727] md/raid1:md0: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
[    2.391929] md0: bitmap file is out of date (915404 < 915405) -- forcing full recovery
[    2.391989] md0: bitmap file is out of date, doing full recovery
```

How to ensure the array will be clean during a shutdown?

Comment: Is the RAID configured to have the write cache set to `on`? Is this system used as a typical desktop, or does it act more as a server? 

Comment: I have no idea about this write cache, and it is a typical desktop.

Comment: How is the OS being shut down? Correctly or by the power switch?

Comment: I click on XFCE Shutdown button and it then does its thing, so I hope this is a correct shutdown. But I couldn't find in the systemd units where it waits for a clean md0 shutdown. Maybe this is related to my / being on raid?